# Menu not clickable on one page only

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a site set up using Ruby on Rails and, for some unexplicable reason, the menu/navbar (which is the same across the whole site) isn't registering clicks for one specific page.

You can see the page I'm talking about [here](http://www.linchpinrealty.com/buyers/new).  When you try to click on any of the menu items or the top left logo (which usually takes you to the index page), nothing happens.  It works properly on every page in the site but this one.

I've tried looking for overlapping objects that might be getting in the way using devtools, but to no avail.  Also, the cursor changes to a hand when you mouse over the links, so I know it's at least registering them.

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: It is because it is your only pages which is in another subdirectory.

Comment: There is an error in some javascript when clicking in those links: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following javascript in that page, the `event.preventDefault()` is your problem.

```
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
      }, 500);
  });
```

Either remove that code or do scope the targets of that event listener.

Comment: Ahhh!  Yes!  As soon as I changed the 'a' to my button ID it worked perfectly!  Thank you!